# Как использовать значение вложенного запроса?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

столкнулся с такой задачей

Есть 2 таблички **product** и **pdate**

В таблице **pdate** - 2 поля [ start, update ]

В таблице **product** - есть поле [ type ]

Суть задачи :

1. Нужно найти свежую дату в таблице **pdate** в поле **start**(но если есть **update** то она актуальнее)
2. сравнивать продукты нужно только с определённым **type** к примеру **21** для таких продуктов нужно от сегодняшней даты отнять 1 месяц
3. и в итоге нужно посчитать количество продуктов (на основании данных 1 и 2), и если дата start or update [1 шаг ] меньше чем сегодня-1 месяц [ 2 шаг ] - тогда считаем

---

Мои мысли и что пробовал.

В sql у меня опыта мало, я попробовал все строки с условий (их 3) написать под `select`, и то как 3 строкой идёт `count` то первые 2 ушли в `group by` но 3му шагу нужны данные с прошлых 2х шагов. В последствии я понял что `count` и тому подобные функции не могут тянуть данные с `group by`
Почитав пару статей понял что для подобных вопросов есть вложенные запросы, но и тут желаемый результат я не получил.

```
select
  y.result 
from (select 
         nvl(tda.start,tda.update) as fresh_date
         ,case where tpo.type = '21' there add_mothe(to_date(sysdate),-1) end 
          as product_date
         ,count(case where res > fdate there 1 else null end) result        
      from pdate as tda inner join product as tpo on tda.id=tpo.id
group by nvl(tda.start,tda.update),
   case where tpo.type = '21' there add_mothe(to_date(sysdate),-1) end
)y;
```

И в 3 вложенных тоже.

```
select
  y.result 
from (select 
         nvl(tda.start,tda.update) as fresh_date
         ,case where tpo.type = '21' there add_mothe(to_date(sysdate),-1) end 
          as product_date
         ,(select count(case where res > fdate there 1 else null end)
          from pdate as tda inner join product as tpo on tda.id=tpo.id ) result        
      from pdate as tda inner join product as tpo on tda.id=tpo.id
group by nvl(tda.start,tda.update),
   case where tpo.type = '21' there add_mothe(to_date(sysdate),-1) end
)y;
```

Пробовал по разному, но без результата

Comment: Добавте в вопрос пример исходных данных и ожидаемый результат. Желательно на фиддле, например - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Товарищи, получилось!)

Хочу поделиться решением.

Для решения нужно 3 вложенных

```
select
  y.result 
from (select 
         count(case where product_date > fresh_date there 1 else null end) result
       from select (
                nvl(tda.start,tda.update) as fresh_date
                ,case where tpo.type = '21' there add_mothe(to_date(sysdate),-1) end 
                as product_date
             from pdate as tda inner join product as tpo on tda.id=tpo.id)
```

А для новеньких пару важных подсказок через которые я спотыкался.
Тут 3 вложенных запроса.
показываем таблицы в 3 вложенном, что бы в предыдущих уровнях запросов иметь доступ к полям из таблицы их нужно объявить в том запросе где прописываем таблицы.

т.е

```
select
     ...
from (select 
           id // даже если в таблице есть поле id в этом уровне он его не видит.
      from select
              client
           from t1)
```

```
select
     ...
from (select 
           id // теперь все увидит
      from select
              client
              ,id   // добавляем
           from t1)
```

Надеюсь эта информация будет вам полезна, хорошего дня !